# CSS separate background stats

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following lines of code:

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg')
```

Is there any way I can separate the 'url' part to another line?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can put any whitespace between the parts of a property value.

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), 
            url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg')
```

… but when specifying multiple background images, you have to specify them all at once, so you can't split it between multiple property assignments.